# Fade element in and run a callback

Tags: javascript

Ok, I've tried this many different ways. I'm trying to learn javascript without always resorting to jQuery. I'm trying to create similar functionality for fading an element in and then out (using callbacks as arguments).

Given this element:
`<div id="something">asdf</div>`

When I run this javascript (or something similar), I end up either getting flickering effects (I think it's from both the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions running) or just having it fade in. More problems happen when I try to do this to several elements at once (in a for loop), but I'm guessing that "closures" will be the answer to that. One thing at a time.

```
function setOpacity(element, value) {
    element.style.opacity = value/100;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
}

function fadeIn(element, speed, callback) {
    if( ! speed ) { speed = 1000; }
    var speed = speed / 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        setTimeout((function(i){ return function(){ setOpacity(element, i); } })(i), (i * speed));
    }
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            return function() {
                callback();
            }
        }, (100 * speed));
    }
}

function fadeOut(element, speed, callback) {
    if( ! speed ) { speed = 1000; }
    var speed = speed / 100;
    for (var i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
        setTimeout((function(i){ return function(){ setOpacity(element, i); } })(i), ((100 - i) * speed));
    }
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            return function(){
                callback();
            }
        }, (100 * speed));
    }
}

element = document.getElementById('something');
element.onclick = function() {
    fadeIn(element, 1000, function() {
        fadeOut(element, 1000, function() {
            // All done
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
var timer, i = 0;
timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(++i == 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        callback();
        return;
    }
    setOpacity(element, i);
}, speed);
```

Launching 101 timers at once isn't that friendly to the browser but a single interval timer that stops itself isn't a big deal. Also, 100 iterations is probably too high, 15-20 is probably more than enough; you can play with the number after you've switched to `setInterval`, you might be surprised how low you can take it without affecting the visual performance.

Comment: Update: Nowadays it is preferred to use `requestAnimationFrame` over `setInterval` for animation purposes.